# String slicing in python

Tags: python, substring, slice

I want to slice word from the end.Suppose, I have some line with case sensitives(Upper/lower case)

```
Abc Defg Hijk Lmn
Xyz Lmn jkf gkjhg
```

I want to slice them as like below :

```
Abc Defg Hijk
Abc Defg
Abc
```

Then I need to take each sliced line in variables so that I can use them to  search in some text file & return the whole text:

Suppose I have text :

```
 Akggf Abc Defg Hijk fgff jfkjgk djkfkgf     
 Akgff Abc fgff jfkjgk djkfkgf     
 Akggef Abc Defg  fgff jfkjgk djkfkgf
 gjshgs gskk Xyz Lmn jkf
 fgsgdf fkgksk Xyz Lmn
```

Any suggestions please.Thanks!

Comment: so those selections are the first 3, 2, and 1, words of the line?

Comment: @Dan D.:Yes, it is. But I need to do this process globally & take each sliced line in varriables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the following code:

```
dataStr = 'Abc Defg Hijk Lmn'
for word in reversed(dataStr.split()):
    # do something with word
```

OR:

```
dataStr = 'Abc Defg Hijk Lmn'
removeLastWord = lambda line: ' '.join([word for word in line.split()[:-1]])
dataStr = removeLastWord(dataStr)
>>> 'Abc Defg Hijk'
dataStr = removeLastWord(dataStr)
>>> 'Abc Defg'
dataStr = removeLastWord(dataStr)
>>> 'Abc'
```

I have read your update and think that Roman's solution feats your needs. You can update your code the following way:

```
searchTxt = """Abc Defg Hijk Lmn
Xyz Lmn jkf gkjhg"""

data = """kggf **Abc Defg Hijk** fgff jfkjgk djkfkgf
 Akggf **Abc ** fgff jfkjgk djkfkgf
 Akggf **Abc Defg  fgff jfkjgk djkfkgf
 gjshgs gskk **Xyz Lmn jkf**
 fgsgdf fkgksk **Xyz Lmn**"""

searchWords = []
for line in (line for line in searchTxt.split('\n') if line.strip()):
    words = line.split()
    searchWords.extend([' '.join(words[:i]) for i in xrange(len(words), 0, -1)])

searchWords = sorted(searchWords, key=len, reverse=True)# to look first for the longest string match

res = set([line for sword in searchWords for line in data.split('\n') if sword in line])

# OR

res = []
for line in data.split('\n'):
    for sword in searchWords:
        if sword in line:
            res.append(line)
            break
```

And if you need to get a full text:

```
resultText = '\n'.join(res)
```

Comment: @ Artsiom Rudzenka : Could you please a bit elaborate.I mean how to get the desired sliced line for many dataStr.Thanks!

Comment: Give me an example so i will be able to help you.

Comment: @ Artsiom Rudzenka : I have updated the question.Could you please have a look!

Comment: Could you please have a look over this part `searchWords.extend([' '.join(words[:i]) for i in xrange(len(words), 0, -1)])`

Comment: What is wrong with it? I have copied all code and rerun it - all is ok

Comment: If I print `searchWords` get like two times everything i.e. `['Abc Defg Hijk Lmn', 'Abc Defg Hijk', 'Abc Defg', 'Abc', 'Abc Defg Hijk Lmn', 'Abc Defg Hijk', 'Abc Defg', 'Abc']
['Abc Defg Hijk Lmn', 'Abc Defg Hijk', 'Abc Defg', 'Abc', 'Abc Defg Hijk Lmn', 'Abc Defg Hijk', 'Abc Defg', 'Abc', 'Xyz Lmn jkf gkjhg', 'Xyz Lmn jkf', 'Xyz Lmn', 'Xyz']`

Comment: You can contact me using skype( you can find it within linked profile in my info)

Comment: I can't update code till you give me sample of your input, i have checked my code twice in console and pycharm and it gives me the very same result.

Answer (score 5):

Use `rsplit` function:

```
>>> s = 'Abc Defg Hijk Lmn'
>>> s.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
'Abc Defg Hijk'
>>> s = s.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
>>> s.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
'Abc Defg'
```

and so on...

Another variant:

```
>>> words = s.split()
>>> [' '.join(words[:i]) for i in range(len(words), 0, -1)]
['Abc Defg Hijk Lmn', 'Abc Defg Hijk', 'Abc Defg', 'Abc']
```

Comment: `[' '.join(words[:i]) for i in range(len(words), 0, -1)]`
Like it! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To create a list from string:

```
a="Abc Defg Hijk Lmn".split()
```

look at it:

```
['Abc', 'Defg', 'Hijk', 'Lmn']
```

slice it, to remove last entry:

```
a[:-1]
```

This gives:

```
['Abc', 'Defg', 'Hijk']
```

To join it into a string again:

```
" ".join(a[:-1])
```

gives:

```
'Abc Defg Hijk'
```

Now, repeat that in a loop...

Comment: Note that `s != " ".join(s.split())` while `s == " ".join(s.split(" "))` when `s = "Two  spaces"`